# QT5: Multithread Tcp server doesn't send data to user

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, tcp

I'm new in QT5 and decided to create simple multithreaded tcp server. I've read examples provided in QT but they have additional functions and complexity which I'm trying to avoid at this point. Here is my code:
**server.h**

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include "threadz.h"
class Server : public QTcpServer
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);

 signals:

 public slots:
  void newConnection();
 private:
  QTcpServer *serv;

};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

**threadz.h**

```
#ifndef THREADZ_H
#define THREADZ_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include "server.h"
class Threadz : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
   explicit Threadz(QObject *parent = 0);
   void run(QTcpServer *serv);

  signals:

  public slots:

};

#endif // THREADZ_H
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) :
   QTcpServer(parent)
{
  serv = new QTcpServer(this);

  connect(serv, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));

  if(!serv->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234))
  {
    qDebug() << "Error";
  }

}

void Server::newConnection()
{
   Threadz *thred = new Threadz();
   thred->start();

}
```

**threadz.cpp**

```
#include "threadz.h"
Threadz::Threadz(QObject *parent) :
  QThread(parent)
{
}


void Threadz::run(QTcpServer *serv)
{
  QTcpSocket *socket  = serv->nextPendingConnection();

  socket->write("Hello!r\n");
  socket->waitForBytesWritten();
  socket->close();


}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "simplehttp.h"
#include "server.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  Server gio;


  return a.exec();
}
```

Basically, Im trying to create new thread for every client that connects server. But problem is that when I run this code and connect server with  *telnet 127.0.0.1 1234* nothing is printed on the screen. No errors but nothing is printed neither. Im using ubuntu 14.04. Sorry if question is silly and thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you step through this code in a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QThread::run`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#run) function is not implemented.

> `void QThread::run() [virtual protected]`
>
> The starting point for the thread. After calling start(), the newly created thread calls this function. The default implementation simply calls exec().
>
> You can reimplement this function to facilitate advanced thread management. Returning from this method will end the execution of the thread.

Instead you implemented `void Threadz::run(QTcpServer *serv)` but **something needs to call this function**.

Comment: oh yes... I have another question what is the difference between nextPendingConnection and incomingConnection i've read the documentation but i didn't really get the difference

Comment: @Ojs You should really be asking a new question... Anyway, `incommingConnection` is `protected` and can't be called when you create an instance of the `QTcpServer` class. Furthermore, the documentation states it emits the `newConnection` signal. The `nextPendingConnection` is a `public` function that may be called to provide access to the `QTcpSocket` (i.e., it has a return value whereas `incommingConnection` doesn't) and you can key off the `newConnection` signal to know when to call the `nextPendingConnection` function.

Comment: so basically incomingConnection is a function which is called everytime someone connects to server and it emits the newConnection function?

Comment: This is exactly what the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) states. "This virtual function is called by QTcpServer when a new connection is available. ... Finally newConnection() is emitted."